# How can I add previous years data to this SQL query (also can it be made simpler at all)?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have started using Highcharts and come up with the below SQL query to put data on the chart.

It is showing the number of orders a customer has placed per month for the current year.

```
SELECT    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(Orders.OrdDate,'MM'),'Month'), COUNT(Orders.OrdNo)
FROM      Orders
WHERE     Orders.CusNo = '" . $_SESSION['customer'] . "'
AND       Orders.EntryDate LIKE '%-14'
GROUP BY  TO_CHAR(TRUNC(Orders.EntryDate,'MM'),'Month')
```

### Question

1. Can this SQL query be made simpler at all as it's pretty messy?
2. How can I add the previous years data to the same SQL query?

At the moment I am using the results in Highcharts like this:

oci_execute($result);

```
      while ($row = oci_fetch_array($result)) {
         $data0[] = $row['0'];
         $data1[] = $row['1'];
      }

      ...

      xAxis: {
          categories: ["<?php echo join($data0, '","') ?>"]
      },

      series: [{
         name: 'Current Year',
         color: '#2196f3',
         data: [<?php echo join($data1, ',') ?>]
      }],
```

Ideally:

`$data0` would be the month e.g. January.

`$data1` would be the number of orders in that month for the current year.

`$data2` would be the number of orders in that month for the previous year.

I just can't work out how to do this in a single SQL query.

I am using Oracle 8i.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write the query using table aliases:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(o.OrdDate, 'MM'), 'Month'), COUNT(o.OrdNo)
FROM Orders o
WHERE o.CusNo = '" . $_SESSION['customer'] . "' AND o.EntryDate LIKE '%-14'
GROUP BY  TO_CHAR(TRUNC(o.EntryDate, 'MM'), 'Month');
```

I am a little concerned that the `where` clause uses `EntryDate` and the `select` is using `OrdDate`.  Let me assume, though, that that is intentional.  If you want this by month for two years, I would use a numeric month format rather than the name, and fix the date comparison in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(o.OrdDate, 'YYYY-MM'), COUNT(o.OrdNo)
FROM Orders o
WHERE o.CusNo = '" . $_SESSION['customer'] . "' AND
      EXTRACT(year FROM EntryDate) IN (2014, 2013)
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(o.OrdDate, 'YYYY-MM');
```

Note that you do not need to truncate the date before using `to_char()`.

EDIT:

If you want multiple columns, just use conditional aggregation.  I would still stick with numbers for the months, though:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(o.OrdDate, 'MM'),
       SUM(case when EXTRACT(year FROM EntryDate) = 2013 then 1 else 0 end) as val_2013,
       SUM(case when EXTRACT(year FROM EntryDate) = 2014 then 1 else 0 end) as val_2014
FROM Orders o
WHERE o.CusNo = '" . $_SESSION['customer'] . "' AND
      EXTRACT(year FROM EntryDate) IN (2014, 2013)
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(o.OrdDate, 'MM');
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. The idea though is the X axis would contain `January` etc. I could then have `$data1` would be the number of orders in that month for the current year and `$data2` would be the number of orders in that month for the previous year. Your answer would cause duplicate months along the X axis I think. Is it not possible to have 3 rows returned, `Month`, `Current Year` and `Previous Year` via SQL?